# South not working in Webfaction

Tags: django, webfaction

I'm using webfaction server and I'm trying to use south on a django app.
I installed south with

```
pip install south --no-use-wheel
```

And it was installed.
But, when I try

```
python2.7 manage.py help
```

I can't see south commands.
What can I do?

Comment: Did you add south to your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: You should to add south to `INSTALLED_APPS`. You can check with `python2.7 manage.py`

Comment: Thanks! Already solved

Answer (score 1):

The solution was just add the app to INSTALLED_APPS